# How to get second matched object while using .find method in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using following code to get plan details from a website.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import urllib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice


page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.t-mobile.com/shop/plans/individual-plans.aspx').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

#find the container for all the plans
tabcontent = soup.find('div', {"id": "divIndFamilyDetails"})
containers = tabcontent.findAll('ul', {"class": "plans"})

for plan in containers:
  planTitle = plan.find("li", {"class": "detail"})
  if planTitle:
       title = planTitle.find("h3").text     
       print title
```

Currently `print title` is printing 1st matched title, plan variable have one more variable with same class and element combination. I want to print that.

I tried using `findNext` also but it again printed the same results. I don't know how to accomplish this using `findAll` method. Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` returns a list, so just reference the index:

```
title2 = planTitle.findAll("h3")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your own method:

```
def find_second(container, item):
    idx1 = container.find(item)
    return container[idx1+1:].find(item) + idx1
```

Comment: I defined this method in the code, and made the following change `planTitle = plan.find_second("li", {"class": "detail"})` It is giving me `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error.

Comment: I tried using this also `planTitle = find_second(plan,zip("li", {"class": "detail"}))` but it is giving me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'` error

Comment: Actually, I tried your script myself and am getting errors as well. Somehow bs4 doesn't find the `<div>`-tag with the id you're searching - even though I see it in the string.